# Editing imported KML in ArcGIS Earth?

Tags: kml, editing, arcgis-earth

The recent release of ["new Google Earth"](https://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2017/04/first-review-new-google-earth.html) appears completely unsuited to the tasks for which I use Google Earth, so I figured it was time to see if I should migrate to ArcGIS Earth as was [suggested to me last year.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/190864/71380)

I installed [ArcGIS Earth](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis-earth) and found a way to import `My Places.kmz` from Google Earth.  However it acts like all the data is read-only.  I cannot figure out how to edit placemarks and paths or even rearrange them in the Layer List.

Is it possible to edit imported KML in ArcGIS Earth?

Answer (score 3):

From [GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/176011) (and an Esri staff member) it looks like the functionality that you seek is not yet available, but is coming.  When asked whether spatial data created in ArcGIS Earth could be exported to KMZ, the response was:

> We simply don't have the KML export capability yet... and the drawing
>   elements are not created as hidden KML under the hood.  This simple
>   use case is planned for the 1.2 update at the UC timeframe.  More
>   advanced KML editing will be later in the roadmap.

To help make this a priority I suggest creating an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas) so that you and others can vote for it.

Comment: Thanks.  I am not married to the idea of keeping everything in KML; is there a native ArcGIS Earth format I can import `My Places.kmz` into, and then edit from there?

Comment: That may be best asked as a separate question but in ArcGIS Earth 1.4 (which I only just upgraded to) I cannot see any option to do that.